# hide div if clicked outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m having a little trouble with this JQuery function.

Basically, I have a div, that when clicked, shows another Div. It’s set to a toggle, actually, so it toggles on/off when you click.

I want to have it where if you click on anywhere outside of the opened div (that appears after you click on the first div), the div that was opened is closed.

```
$("#idSelect").click(function() {
   $("#idDiv").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT :** A better approach here:
 [How to create a custom modal popup - and how to close it clicking outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283652/close-display-block-divs-if-open-by-clicking-anywhere-on-body)

---

<s>[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/alajaz/1/edit)</s>

```
$( "#idSelect" ).click(function( e ) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   $("#idDiv").toggle();
});

$( "#idDiv" ).on('click',function( e ) {
     e.stopPropagation();
});

$( document ).on('click', function( e ) {
   if( e.target.id != 'idDiv' ){
       $( "#idDiv" ).hide();
   }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
$(document).click(function() {
   if($(window.event.target).attr('id') != 'idSelect')
       $("#idDiv").hide();
});
```

Comment: Change `$("#idDiv").toggle();` to `.hide()` otherwise clicking on any element will toggle the div

Comment: @Zoltan Toah: YOu are correct

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click",function(e) {
   if ($(e.target).is("#idDiv, #idDiv *"))
       $("#idDiv").show();
   else
       $("#idDiv").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[**jQuery-outside-events**](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/) plugin adds support for the following events

> clickoutside, dblclickoutside, focusoutside, bluroutside,
>   mousemoveoutside, mousedownoutside, mouseupoutside, mouseoveroutside,
>   mouseoutoutside, keydownoutside, keypressoutside, keyupoutside,
>   changeoutside, selectoutside, submitoutside.

Applied to your case you can do

```
    $("#idDiv").on("clickoutside", function( ) {
        $("#idDiv").hide();
    });

    $("#idSelect").on("click", function( e ) {
        $("#idDiv").toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/cpDHg/1/)