# jQuery toggle hide on click elsewhere

Tags: jquery, toggle

This may be a very simple but never used this type of things so no idea how to do.

I am using fadeToggle to show hide div an

```
$('#account-toggle').click(     
function(){
    $('#account-toggle').toggleClass('account-active');
    $('.account-group').fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

It is working fine.. (obviously nothing complex :P ) now what I want is to hide it when user click elsewhere on the screen.

Can anyone help me to make it happen?... thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#account-toggle').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('account-active');
    $('.account-group').fadeToggle('fast');
});

$(document).click(function(){
    $('#account-toggle.account-active').removeClass('account-active');
    $('.account-group:visible').hide();
});
```

- `$(document).click` event is triggered whenever a user click anywhere in the page.
- It might happen that the user clicks on the `account-toggle` element. This will trigger both the `#account-toggle` & `document` event due to event bubbling. To stop that we have used the [`e.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) function here.

Comment: +1 additionally instead of **always** removeClass and hide repeatedly you could test for `.is(':visible')`

Comment: Wonderful! it works perfect and the way I want. Can you please explain a bit to understand how it works?

Comment: @PalashMondal I would give you another +1 if you used `$(this)`

Comment: @PalashMondal and another +1 if you added some explanation and an example using `event.target`

Comment: @PalashMondal here is how to do it using e.target http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514932/hide-div-if-clicked-outside-of-it (ohh, look my answer! **☻**)

Comment: one issue I found.. my div containing input field and when I click on that (focus) to type it's hiding the div too.. any solution?

Comment: @pixelngrain can you setup a jsbin.com ?

Comment: Okay give me a moment please