# How to hide ul using jquery when users click elsewhere

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have this code to toggle the `ul` visibility.

```
$('.cliackable').click(function(){ $(this).find('ul').toggle(); });

$('.cliackable').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

How do I toggle this when user clicks outside the `ul`?

I tried using the answer here but to no avail : [jQuery toggle hide on click elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385993/jquery-toggle-hide-on-click-elsewhere)

**Update**

my CSS looks like this

```
<!-- language: css -->
html, body {height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;}
#navigation-main {width:65px;margin-left:10px;}
#navigation-main .sf-menu-main li ul {display:none;}
#navigation-main .sf-menu-main li li {background:#e73420;border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); width: 235px; clear:both; padding:5px 0px 5px 15px; color:#fff;}
#navigation-main .sf-menu-main li li a {width: 250px; padding:5px 10px 5px 15px; color:#fff;}
```

and the html

```
<div id="navigation-main">
    <ul class="sf-menu-main">
        <li style="color:#fff;" class="clickable">
            Menu
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="login-head-font" href="">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="login-head-font" href="">Events</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried using your js but didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you expected?

http://jsfiddle.net/utgc0981/2/

HTML

```
<div id="navigation-main">
    <ul class="sf-menu-main">
        <li class="clickable">Menu
            <ul class="sf-menu-sub">
                <li> <a class="login-head-font" href="">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a class="login-head-font" href="">Events</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    var sf_menu_sub = $('.sf-menu-sub');
    $('.clickable').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        sf_menu_sub.toggle();
    });
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        sf_menu_sub.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: perfect!! works seemlessly .. just one more query.. what if i have two similar menus ? should create two different scripts for both or is there a way around in the same cause if i click on one both ul get showed up

Answer (score -1):

Check for `$(e.target)` . If it is anything else except the `ul` or if it is the `body` then hide it else show it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/344/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.checked').click(function (e) {
        $('ul').show();
    });
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('body')) {
            $('ul').hide();
        }
    })
});
```