# Toggle and Hide Login form when users click anywhere using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, authentication

So I have a Login form within a `li` tag.

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <ul class="pull-right">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-bar">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-bar">E</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="lion">Login</a>
            <div class="eagle form">
                <form>
                    ...
                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to `show()` the form when users click on `login`, and `hide()`the form when users click elsewhere, using jquery.

I use this jquery code after read this answer: [How to hide ul using jquery when users click elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949198/how-to-hide-ul-using-jquery-when-users-click-elsewhere)

JS

```
$(function () {
  var sesion = $('.eagle.form');
  $('.lion').on('click', function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      sesion.toggle();
  });
  $(document).on('click', function (e) {
      sesion.toggle();
  });
});
```

However, when login form shows up and I want to interact with the fields on it, it hides again.

How can I fix the code? I think I'm missing one line.

Any suggestions to solve the problem are appreacited!

Comment: See this codepen mate: http://codepen.io/pen/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the solution from this question: [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it?rq=1)

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $('.form');
    if (!container.is(e.target)
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.hide();
    }

    $('HERE-GOES-li-CONTAINER').click( function(event) {
        $('.form').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ray716/a2d5vv2y/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </li>
  <div class="meh">
    <li> <a href="#" class="toggleForm">Form</a>
      <ul class="form">
        <li>
          <form>
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="submit" />
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Js:

```
$(".form").hide();
$(".toggleForm").click(function() {
  $(".form").toggle();
});
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest(".meh").length == 0) {
    $(".form").hide();
  }
});
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: It works great when I click on `body`, but it doesn't `hide` when I click on `nav` elements. I think the example provided is helpful.