# someting like submenu on input click and close it on losing focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something like submenu on input click and close it on losing focus with jQuery.
Only accomplished using mouseup like this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){

   var container = $(".container");

   if (!container.is(e.target)
       && container.has(e.target).length === 0
       && !$(".input").is(e.target))
   {
       $('.submenu').removeClass('submenu');
   }
});
```

here is my results:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lwfhbdmp/8/

this works OK, but I think it's too complex and maybe there is a simpler solution for this?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwfhbdmp/13/)***

A cleaner solution:

```
$(function(){

    var $submenu,
        contHov = 1,
        $container = $('.container').hover(function(){ contHov^=1; }); // Tog flag on hover

    $(document).on('mouseup keyup', function( e ){
        if(contHov||e.which==27) $submenu.removeClass("submenu");
    });

    $(".input").on("click", function(e){
        $submenu = $(this).closest("div").toggleClass('submenu');
    });

    // That's it. From now on, whenever you desire to
    // reference to the currently active 'submenu'
    // simply use the $submenu variable:

    $(".btn-inside").on("click", function(){
        alert("Clicked");
        $submenu.removeClass("submenu");
    });

});
```

...and you can even use <kbd>ESC</kbd> to close the `$submenu`

<sub>[How to close-hide DIV clicking outside of it (but not inside)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140278/how-to-close-hide-div-clicking-outside-of-it-but-not-inside/6144189#6144189)</sub>

Comment: yes it works but in console I'm getting an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeClass' of undefined"

Comment: another question is, why the $container variable is unused ?