# How to close menu dropdown when click on body

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu that works fine. The button allows me to open and close the menu, however, if I click on the body page the menu does not close, only clicking on the button can close it.

So I would like it to close even if I click on the body of the page or anything else that isn't the button. I'm trying to close the menu with document.body.addEventListener but it doesn't work, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me by pointing me the right way?

I appreciate any response, thanks.

```js
var usermenu = document.querySelector(".user_menu_button");
function userMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mts_menu");
   if (x.classList.toggle ("show")) {
    usermenu.innerHTML = '<i class="icn_button fa-solid fa-xmark"></i><span class="txt_button">Account</span>';
}  else {
   usermenu.innerHTML = '<i class="icn_button fa-solid fa-bars"></i><span class="txt_button">Account</span>';
   }
}

 // Close Menu clicking on body or Anywhere
    document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var x = document.getElementById("mts_menu");
        // For var x
        if (e.target.id !== "mts_menu" && x.classList.contains("show")) {
          x.classList.toggle("show");
        }
    });
```

```css
/*Button Toggle Menu*/
.user_menu_button {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    background: #3D4350!important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 14px!important;
    line-height: 2;
}

.icn_button {
    margin: 0;
}

.icn_button:before, .icn_button:after {
    margin: 0;
}

.txt_button {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

/*Items menu*/
.user_menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.user_menu.header {
  padding: 15px 15px;   
}

/*Menu header info*/
.display.name {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #303238;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.display.mail {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #1E70EB;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

hr.divider-menu {
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

/*Text Link css*/
.mnu_margin {
  margin: 7px 0;    
}

.user_menu.item > a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 15px; 
    color: #212629;
}

.user_menu.item:hover > a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #1E70EB;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.user_menu.item > a .link_text {
  font-size: 14px; 
  color: #212629;
}

.user_menu.item:hover > a .link_text {
  color: #fff;    
}


/*Icon Items Menu*/
.icn_menu:before, .icon_menu:after {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 16px
}

.icn_menu {
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
}

/* User Menu For header website */
.mts_menu_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.dropdown_box {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.mts_dropdown_content {
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 240px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 5px 15px 0px;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50px;
  height: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.2s, max-height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s, top 0.2s, height 0.2s;
}

.mts_dropdown_content.show {
   height: 100%;
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
   top: 0;
   transition: visibility 0.2s, max-height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s, top 0.2s, height 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="userMenu()" class="user_menu_button">
     <i class="icn_button fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
     <span class="txt_button">Account</span>
</button>

<div class="mts_menu_container">
  <div class="dropdown_box">
      
   <div id="mts_menu" class="mts_dropdown_content">
    <div class="user_menu header">
        <span class="display name">Ciao [display_name]</span>
        <span class="display mail">[display_email]</span>
    </div>   
      
     <hr class="divider-menu">  
     
    <div class="mnu_margin"> 
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="/account">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-user"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
     <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="ordini">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-basket-shopping"></i>
         <span class="link_text">I miei ordini</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="libreria">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-cloud-arrow-down"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Downloads</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="impostazioni">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-gear"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Impostazioni</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item last">
        <a href="wp-login.php?action=logout">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Logout</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
   
   </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Comment: See: [Close/hide an element when clicking outside of it (but not inside)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6140278/383904)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in this way, thanks also to the help of @Emiel
I added `event.stopPropagation();` and then

```
//Closing Menu Part
const closing = document.querySelector("#mts_menu");
document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  if (!evt.target.closest("#mts_menu")) closing.classList.remove("show");
});
```

```js
var usermenu = document.querySelector(".user_menu_button");
function userMenu() {
  event.stopPropagation(); //For Closing menu   
  var x = document.getElementById("mts_menu");
   if (x.classList.toggle ("show")) {
    usermenu.innerHTML = '<i class="icn_button fa-solid fa-xmark"></i><span class="txt_button">Account</span>';
}  else {
   usermenu.innerHTML = '<i class="icn_button fa-solid fa-bars"></i><span class="txt_button">Account</span>';
   }
}  

//Closing Menu Part
const closing = document.querySelector("#mts_menu");
document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  if (!evt.target.closest("#mts_menu")) closing.classList.remove("show");
});
```

```css
/*Button Toggle Menu*/
.user_menu_button {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    background: #3D4350!important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 14px!important;
    line-height: 2;
}

.icn_button {
    margin: 0;
}

.icn_button:before, .icn_button:after {
    margin: 0;
}

.txt_button {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

/*Items menu*/
.user_menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.user_menu.header {
  padding: 15px 15px;   
}

/*Menu header info*/
.display.name {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #303238;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.display.mail {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #1E70EB;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

hr.divider-menu {
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

/*Text Link css*/
.mnu_margin {
  margin: 7px 0;    
}

.user_menu.item > a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 15px; 
    color: #212629;
}

.user_menu.item:hover > a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #1E70EB;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.user_menu.item > a .link_text {
  font-size: 14px; 
  color: #212629;
}

.user_menu.item:hover > a .link_text {
  color: #fff;    
}


/*Icon Items Menu*/
.icn_menu:before, .icon_menu:after {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 16px
}

.icn_menu {
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
}

/* User Menu For header website */
.mts_menu_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.dropdown_box {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.mts_dropdown_content {
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 240px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 5px 15px 0px;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50px;
  height: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.2s, max-height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s, top 0.2s, height 0.2s;
}

.mts_dropdown_content.show {
   height: 100%;
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
   top: 0;
   transition: visibility 0.2s, max-height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s, top 0.2s, height 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="userMenu()" class="user_menu_button">
     <i class="icn_button fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
     <span class="txt_button">Account</span>
</button>

<div class="mts_menu_container">
  <div class="dropdown_box">
      
   <div id="mts_menu" class="mts_dropdown_content">
    <div class="user_menu header">
        <span class="display name">Ciao [display_name]</span>
        <span class="display mail">[display_email]</span>
    </div>   
      
     <hr class="divider-menu">  
     
    <div class="mnu_margin"> 
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="/account">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-user"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
     <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="ordini">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-basket-shopping"></i>
         <span class="link_text">I miei ordini</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="libreria">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-cloud-arrow-down"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Downloads</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="impostazioni">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-gear"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Impostazioni</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item last">
        <a href="wp-login.php?action=logout">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Logout</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
   
   </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Listen for a click event on the `document` object. Inside the handler, check if the clicked element is inside the navigation or not with [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

```
const usermenu = document.querySelector(".user_menu_button")
const menu = document.querySelector('#mts_menu');

document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const isClickedOutsideMenu = event.target.closest('#mts_menu') === null;
  if (isClickedOutsideMenu && menu.classList.contains('open')) {
    menu.classList.remove('open');
    usermenu.innerHTML = '<i class="icn_button fa-solid fa-bars"></i><span class="txt_button">Account</span>';
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'm trying to implement but can't. What I did was add your code to the script I wrote earlier. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, so I guess I don't have to implement it as you wrote it, right ?

Comment: if i add a div with an id and then edit `document.getElementById("container_test").addEventListener` works. I don't understand why it doesn't work if I remove the getElementById ("container_test") part. i also tried `document.body.addEventListener` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does the console present you with any errors? My guess is that the `usermenu` variable in my script and in your script clash because `usermenu` is already defined in your script. Please let me know.